# How can i get text of the element in the list, using random select?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm just looking for the method, that will help me to get text value of the element selected randomly from the dropdown list using Selenium Webdriver on Java.

Here is HTML of the dropdown list:

```
<select name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$cphContentLeft$ddlCabinType" id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cphContentLeft_ddlCabinType" class="ddlWidth form-control" onchange="BookOnline.onCabinTypeChange();" style="margin-top: 4px;">
    <option value="0"> Please Select </option>
    <option value="Inside">Inside</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="Outside">Outside</option>
    <option value="Balcony">Balcony</option>
    <option value="Suite">Suite</option>

</select>
```

Here is my code:

```
public void selectRandomValue() {
    Select select = new Select(getWebElement());
    List<WebElement> weblist = select.getOptions();
    int options = weblist.size();
    Random random = new Random();
    int option = random.nextInt(options);
    String value = Integer.toString(option);
     logMessage("Select random " + value + " value in"); // In logMessage i want to recieve text instead of number.
    select.selectByIndex(option);
}
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: do you know java just works on server side? You have 2 options **a) use javascript** to get selected value  or **b)** make an `Ajax` call to pass to java the value (oh no, this means to **use javascript** again to get selected value!)

Comment: this method gives me only integer value of a number of selected option, but i want to receive whole name, for example "Suite"

Comment: @JordiCastilla  I'm assuming the reason why the code is in Java is because its running within a test harness.

Comment: Guys, i've updated java code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively:

```
String value = weblist.get(option).getText();
```

if it's the displayed text you want (which seems to be the same in your example, but which doesn't have to be).

Answer (score 1):

```
String value = weblist.get(option).getAttribute("value");
```

Should do the trick if I understood this correctly. Or if you want the text:

```
String value = weblist.get(option).getText();
```

Just look at the [documentation](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html).

Comment: i want to get text only, because values could be "5647675"(ex,) in other dropdowns.

Comment: Then it's just `getText()`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will show the text of the selected element in your listbox:

```
Random random = new Random();
int optionIndex = random.nextInt(listbox.getOptions().size()-1);
listbox.selectByIndex(optionIndex++);
String text = listbox.getFirstSelectedOption().getText();
System.out.println(text);
```